# ExtJS grid filters: how can I load 'list' filter options from external json?

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, grid, store

I have a ExtJS (4.0) grid and it works fine. Now I want it to advance it a bit by adding filters to it. I want users to be able to filter items by the status.

I have created the following store:

```
var status_store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Statuses',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/json/statuses/',
        reader: 'json'
    }
});
```

and I can see it loads, /json/statuses/ will return the following json object:

```
[
  {
    "name": "OK",
    "isActive": true
  },
  {
    "name": "Outdated",
    "isActive": true
  },
  {
    "name": "New",
    "isActive": true
  }
]
```

Now I define the filters:

```
var filters = {
    ftype: 'filters',
    encode: encode,
    local: local,
    filters: [{
        type: 'list',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        store: 'status_store',
        labelField: 'name'          
    }]
};
```

and add the filter to my column definition:

```
{text: 'Status', width: 120, dataIndex: 'status', sortable: true, filterable: true, filter: {type: 'list'}},
```

What happens is I get the following error when the grid loads:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object json has no method 'read' (ext-all-debug.js:25702)
```

and when I click on the column header for the menu:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object status_store has no method 'on' (ListMenu.js:69)
```

How can I fix this or am I doing something conceptually wrong?

Here is the full quote of my code just in case: http://pastebin.com/SNn6gFJz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for Diagnosing the problem. The 4.1 fix is this modify ListMenu.js

in the else part of the constructor

replace

```
        me.store.on('load', me.onLoad, me);
```

with

```
        // add a listener to the store object
        var storeObject = Ext.StoreMgr.lookup(me.store);
        storeObject.on('load', me.onLoad, me);
        me.store = storeObject;
```

Comment: As pointed out in other comments, the issue is that the ListFilter class requires an actual store object, not a store config or store id string like you can use in most of the rest of the framework.  The framework code is fine; you're simply not following the API.

Answer (score 0):

```
filters: [{
             type: 'list',
             dataIndex: 'name',
             store: 'status_store',
             labelField: 'name' ,
             options:[a,b]
         }]
```

You also have to give the options in list filters.

Comment: ListFilter accepts either a store reference or options object. The problem here is that the value for store is a string rather than a reference.

Comment: @jd. string containing what? a storeId or store reference variable name? Could you illustrate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121355/remote-filtering-with-listfilter-in-extjs-grid-column-header).

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem. I followed the @jd comment on the other answer here but the options menu just said "loading...". I resolved it with a bit of a hack [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9105431/1062992).