# Extjs dynamic filter

Tags: list, extjs, filter

I have created a filter that contains unik values of column:

```
{
  header   : 'Вопрос А',
  dataIndex: 'answerA',
  itemId: 'answerA',
  width    : 100,
  filter: {
      type: 'list',
      options: this.getStore().collect('answerA'),
  },
  editor: 'textfield'
}
```

When the user inputs new value in the cell of the column this value must appear in the filter. How can I do this?

I have looked at [Extjs Grid Filter - Dynamic ListFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086918/extjs-grid-filter-dynamic-listfilter) but it doesn't help me much.

Answer (score 0):

You should carefully look at `StringFilter.js` file which is at `ux/grid/filter`. I did this myself by adding a `combobox` to each filter. On combo `expand` I update its store by parsing the corresponding column data. Besides I advise you to collect unique values, for this task use `Ext.Array.unique` function. Otherwise, if two cells contain the same data both values will go to the store, which is not good, because any of them will produce the same filtration. I do not attach my code, because it is heavily dependent on my custom data types, but the idea is quite easy, I think.