# Remote Filtering with ListFilter in ExtJS Grid Column Header

Tags: javascript, plugins, extjs, filter, grid

I am using ListFilter plugin to filter results on a Grid panel. The column definition is.

```
{
    header: 'Provider',
    filter: {
        type: 'list',
        store: Ext.getStore('MyApp.store.Provider'),
        dataIndex: 'provider_id',
        labelField: 'name'
    }
}
```

`MyApp.store.Provider` is created as

```
   Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        storeId: 'MyApp.store.Provider',
        autoDestroy: true,
        autoLoad: {start: 0, limit: 50},
        autoSync: true,
        model: 'MyApp.model.Provider',
        pageSize: 50,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            api: {
                create:  'proxy/provider/create',
                read:    'proxy/provider/read',
                update:  'proxy/provider/update',
                destroy: 'proxy/provider/destroy'
            },
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'data',
                successProperty: 'success',
                messageProperty: 'message',
                totalProperty: 'total'
            },
            writer: {
                allowSingle: false,
                type: 'json',
                writeAllFields: false,
                root: 'data'
            }
        }
    });
```

And lastly model `MyApp.model.Provider` is defined as

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Provider', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name: 'provider_id', type: 'int'},
        'name',
        { name: 'create_time', type: 'date', dateFormat: appDateFormat },
        { name: 'status', type: 'int'}
    ],
    idProperty: 'provider_id',
    displayProperty: 'name' // A custom property used for dynamically use the property to display
})
```

Now this code does not show any sub-menu in the filter menu. It just shows loading. See the image.

[image: shows loading]

### Update

I have solved it using following filter config. This actually populates `options` config manually. So no `store` is used here.

```
{
  type: 'list',
  labelField: 'name',
  options: (function () {
    var opts = [];
    fS.load(function (records, operation, success) {
      for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
        var ar = {
          id: records[i].get('provider_id'),
          name: records[i].get('name')
        };

        opts.push(ar);
      }
    });
    return opts;
  })(),
  single: true
}
```

It seems 'id' is hard-coded. `id: records[i].get('provider_id'),` does not look good. Though it works.

But I am still looking for a proper way to do it.

**Note:** The expected behavior can be found on `ExtJS 4.1.1`. See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L8su2/427/). I have reproduced it. But this very same thing does not work on `ExtJS 4.0.7`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extjs Grid Filter - Dynamic ListFilter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086918/extjs-grid-filter-dynamic-listfilter). You could try that other answer and see if it works - the one that isn't mine (I haven't tried it myself so I'm not sure) I went with an alternative.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. Other answer are hacky. Nothing standard. Also they didn't work for me.

Comment: I would retract my "dup" vote [if I could](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/915/176101) now that I understand. This may have been fixed with 4.1.3 but when I was trying to handle this in 4.1.0 it seemed like something broken in the framework so hack solutions were the only things available.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im  I created an override for this to make it work properly with something like the 'idField' config option.  Not sure if you are still interested in that or not, but since it's homebrewed, may be good for ya as it is not proprietary code from sencha.  Drop me a comment if you want it.  I had done it because I ran into the same issue when we were first using 4.0.7 and then updated when we went to 4.1.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I didn't tried this myself but you need to set the ID manually with the `idField` **[property](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.ux.grid.menu.ListMenu-cfg-idField)** [*new to ExtJS4.1.3*] which is per default set to `id`. So I guess this will work:

```
{
    header: 'Provider',
    filter: {
        type: 'list',
        idField: 'provider_id',
        store: Ext.getStore('MyApp.store.Provider'),
        dataIndex: 'provider_id',
        labelField: 'name'
    }
}
```

---

**Update**

OK, I looked at the source and I can now tell you that this is the answer. So will have to either live with your workarround until 4.2 is out or you can apply the following changes to your `Ext.ux.grid.menu.ListMenu` to make it run:

add the `idField` with a default value.

look within the constructor for this lines

```
case 'object': options.push([value.id, value[this.labelField]]); break;
// some more lines
fields: ['id', this.labelField],
```

and replace it with

```
case 'object': options.push([value[me.idField], value[me.labelField]]); break;
// some more lines
fields: [me.idField, me.labelField],
```

and within the onLoad function look for

```
itemValue = records[i].get('id');
```

and replace it with

```
itemValue = records[i].get(me.idField);
```

and that pretty much is it.

Comment: I am not a subscriber of Sencha Support. I can not use this. Note I tried modifying `ListMenu.js` by adding `idField` config earlier. But That didn't work. So I think if it works there might be some other changes. only adding `idField` will not work. I have tested that already.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im I edited my answer and supplied all changes that you should need to make it run.

Comment: I already changed that *hard-coded `id`* to a *configurable settings* earlier *before asking this question*. This code **only** removes the *hard-code `id`*. Nothing else. This does not work. Even I have applied your fix (it adds extra `var me=this`), which still does not fix it.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im Are you sure we are talking about the same file (`examples\ux\grid\menu\ListMenu.js`), which get initialized by `examples\ux\grid\FiltersFeature.js`? Because if you apply the 'fix', which require you to override the first file or apply prototype which overrides the methods. Can you elaborate what fails? Have you removed your workarround?

Comment: I am talking about `http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/extjs-build/examples/ux/grid/menu/ListMenu.js` file. `Can you elaborate what fails?` Ans: It fails to show options. It shows the menu exactly like the screenshot attached to my question. `Have you removed your workarround?` Ans: Yes I have. [This was the code](http://pastie.org/6390947) after using new `ListMenu.js`.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im I would recommend you to replace the whole `ListMenu.js` with the [this one](http://pastie.org/private/i96id3z2gxa7na2hifbdg). You should then be able to simply override all with the upcoming 4.2 release or let it run. All changes I encounter are within this file so it should run after that.

Comment: Okay. I found its not only `ListMenu.js`. **It also depends the changes on `Ext.menu.*` in `4.1`**. The `4.1` version works as expected(see my update on question). But it does not shows menu entries on `4.0`. I can change only `Ext.ux`. But changing all of it is not possible.

Comment: What I like most are downvotes without any comment. There is a reason why there's popup stating to comment the downvote...

Comment: Did you see my update in question? also did you read my last comment? **I down-voted because this does not really solve it**. I can not upgrade extJS version. If I could I wouldn't give a bounty on it. I would try upgrade option first. The app is deployed in production I can not change it.